# SQLite escape string c++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, escaping

Consider the following code

```
char bar[] = "hello world \"One\", two, 'three'";
char *zSQL = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO stuff (`foo`) VALUES ('%q');", bar ) ; 
sqlite3_exec(db, zSQL, 0, 0, 0);
sqlite3_free(zSQL);
/* Produces a exception error */
```

The problem is that the quotes are not getting escaped in the SQL statement. If I was programing in PHP I would use a function like [sqlite_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-escape-string.php) to escape the strings before inserting them in the SQL query but I can not seem to find the equivalent function in C++. I could build my own sqlite_escape_string like function but i am sure there has to be one already written/tested...

Is there a sqlite_escape_string() equivalent function for c++?

Comment: According to the documentation, the `%q` format string is supposed to escape quotes. So the right question to ask is, why isn't it working? Can you post the result of the `sqlite3_mprintf` call?

Comment: @tim, you are correct, there was a syntax error.

Comment: Why not use std::string bla(szYourstring); bla = bla.replace("'", "''"); char* szCharPointer = bla.c_str();

Comment: @Quandary There may be other chars that I don't know of that could cause problems in the future. for example escaped chars, non printable chars, ect..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Use bound parameters.

See:
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Comment: Well, this doesn't always work. You cannot bind parameters when creating a view, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same question that many have posed. There isn't anything built in.

The better solution to string concatenation would be to [bind parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), which sidesteps the escaping issue.