# how to deal with comma and apostrophe chars when inserting into SQLite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

i have string that contains apostrophe  and comma's and when i execute insert into SQLite
it gives me error for example with string like this :

```
...., 'The Smiths - I Know It's Over', .....
"Over": syntax error Unable to execute statement
```

how can i or what can i do to keep the apostrophe's in the string but preform valid insert?
im using Qt c++ .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820374/sqlite-escape-string-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q14):

> (14) How do I use a string literal that contains an embedded single-quote (') character?
>
> The SQL standard specifies that single-quotes in strings are escaped by putting two single quotes in a row. SQL works like the Pascal programming language in the regard. SQLite follows this standard. Example:
>
> INSERT INTO xyz VALUES('5 O''clock');

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be putting arbitrary strings directly into SQL - that's asking for an [injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/). Instead, use [bound parameters](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html); something like:

```
sqlite3_stmt * statement;
sqlite3_prepare(db, "select * from students where name=?", -1, &statement, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, "'; drop table students --", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_step(statement);
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

This will replace the first parameter (`?`) in the query with the given string, with no danger of any `'` character being interpreted as the end of the string, or of any part of the string being executed as SQL.

Comment: What if it is a number with a comma in it? Like german decimals. Really anything with a comma. The question specifically says comma. That is required for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mysql library has a function named mysql_real_escape_string to escape the string. Also, you may use double quotes to surround the string or escape the apostrophe of your input string like this `'The Smiths - I Know It\'s Over',`