# SQL error: near ":02": syntax error

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite

this error happens at line

```
    sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO Device_Details (imei, mobile_num, passwd, Dev_addr, id) "  \
             "VALUES (%s, %d, %s, %s, %d ); ", imei, id, passwd, dev_addr, id);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

where

```
char*  passwd, *imei, *mobile_num, *strtok_var ;
cout<<idIndex << "+" << passwd<<"+"<<imei << "+" << mobile_num << endl;
```

prints
1+abc+abc+abc

table created with

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE Device_Details("  \
            "imei CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
            "mobile_num    INT    NOT NULL," \
            "passwd        CHAR(50) ," \
            "Dev_addr        CHAR(50) ," \
            "id            INT);";

        /* Execute SQL statement */
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0/*callback*/, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Comment: `cout<<...` would hint at this needing a C++ tag instead of C.

Comment: See [preparing queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820374/sqlite-escape-string-c).

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your immediate problem, your strings aren't quoted:

```
sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO Device_Details (imei, mobile_num, passwd, Dev_addr, id) "  \
         "VALUES ('%s', %d, '%s', '%s', %d ); ", imei, id, passwd, dev_addr, id);
```

However, I would highly recommend against manual creation of SQL statements like this.  Doing so exposes a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

For example, suppose someone used the following string for `passwd`:

```sql
', '', 1);  drop table Device_Details; --
```

The resulting SQL would look something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO Device_Details (imei, mobile_num, passwd, Dev_addr, id)
VALUES ('+', 1, '', '', 1);  drop table Device_Details; --', 'dev_addr', 1 );
```

This closes the original `INSERT` statement, adds a  `DELETE TABLE` statement, and comments out the remainder of the original `INSERT`.  And now your table and all the data in it is gone.  Gotta watch out for [little Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)...

[image]

The proper way to handle this is to use prepared statements with parameter binding.  This prevents these kinds of attacks and is more reliable than attempting to manually sanitize the input.

See the [SQLite page for prepared statements](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) for details on how to do this.

Comment: This "solution" creates a SQL injection bug like you say. It's hardly a solution at all, it just weaponizes previously busted code.

Comment: @tadman Added more detail and an example on why SQL injection is bad, and talked more about parameter binding.

Comment: Heh, well, that's more obviously a warning, but a prepared statement version would be best.